# Postgresql WITH statement invalid on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I've got a Rails `find_by_sql` method that works fine locally, in console and the statement also directly in Postgresql, but the statement causes an `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid` error when i deploy it to Heroku.

I'm running Postgresql version 9.0.3 locally and using a shared db on Heroku on their Cedar stack.

The error i'm getting is:

```
PG::Error: ERROR: syntax error at or near "WITH normal_items" LINE 1: WITH normal_items AS (SELECT normal_items_month, count(id)... ^ : WITH normal_items AS (SELECT normal_items_month, count(id) as normal_items_total FROM (SELECT date_trunc('month',created_at) as normal_items_month, id from items WHERE items.a_foreign_key_id IS NULL) z group by normal_items_month), special_items AS (SELECT special_items_month, count(id) as special_items_total FROM (SELECT date_trunc('month',created_at) as special_items_month, id from items WHERE items.a_foreign_key_id IS NOT NULL) x group by special_items_month ) SELECT to_char(month, 'fmMon') as month, coalesce(normal_items_total, 0) as normal_items_total, coalesce(special_items_total, 0) as special_items_total FROM (select generate_series(min(normal_items_month), max(normal_items_month), '1 month'::interval) as month FROM normal_items) m LEFT OUTER JOIN normal_items ON normal_items_month = month LEFT OUTER JOIN special_items ON special_items_month = month
```

For readability the statement is:

```
WITH normal_items AS (SELECT normal_items_month, count(id) as normal_items_total 
                      FROM (SELECT date_trunc('month',created_at) as normal_items_month, id from items 
                            WHERE items.a_foreign_key_id IS NULL) z 
                      group by normal_items_month), 
    special_items AS (SELECT special_items_month, count(id) as special_items_total 
                      FROM (SELECT date_trunc('month',created_at) as special_items_month, id from items 
                            WHERE items.a_foreign_key_id IS NOT NULL) x 
                      group by special_items_month ) 
SELECT 
to_char(month, 'fmMon') as month, 
coalesce(normal_items_total, 0) as normal_items_total, 
coalesce(special_items_total, 0) as special_items_total 
FROM (select generate_series(min(normal_items_month), max(normal_items_month), '1 month'::interval) as month FROM normal_items) m 
LEFT OUTER JOIN normal_items ON normal_items_month = month 
LEFT OUTER JOIN special_items ON special_items_month = month
```

This just a provides me with some stats to use with Google Charts, the output is:

```
Jun 178 0
Jul 0   0
Aug 72  0
Sep 189 0
Oct 24  0
Nov 6   0
Dec 578 0
Jan 0   0
Feb 0   0
Mar 89  0
Apr 607 0
May 281 0
Jun 510 0
Jul 190 0
Aug 0   0
Sep 501 0
Oct 409 0
Nov 704 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku's shared plan runs `PostgreSQL 8.3` which doesn't support `WITH` keyword (it was introduced in [`PostgreSQL 8.4`](http://www.postgresql.org/about/featurematrix/)).

If you upgrade to Heroku's [dedicated database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql) package, you'll be able to use `PostgreSQL 9.1`.

Answer (score 2):

The default Heroku shared DB is Postgres 8.3 - you can use 9.1 in the public beta of the Shared DB plan - more details at https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/4/26/heroku_postgres_development_plan/.

For production you can make use of the newly announced Crane plan at $50 per month https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/4/26/heroku_postgres_development_plan/

Comment: Cheers John. Tempted to try the public beta of 9.1, but given the only thing this particular statement is for is metrics i think i might hold back for the time being until i have enough time to thoroughly test everything.